# json NSJSONSerialization cannot load as the data is html

Tags: ios, json

I get the following _downloadedData:

```
<!-- pageok -->
<!-- managed by puppet -->
<html>
<pre>pageok</pre>
</html>
```

When using the code listed below:

```
- (void)downloadItems
{
    //Download the json file
    NSURL *jsonFileUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.scratchclass.com:80/videos/"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:jsonFileUrl];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
    [request setValue:@"text/html" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setValue:@"gzip" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Encoding"];
    NSURLConnection *connection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    if(!connection){
        NSLog(@"Connection Failed");
    }

}


#pragma mark NSURLConnectionDataProtocol Methods

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    NSLog(@"didReceiveResponse: %@",response);
    // Initialize the data object
    _downloadedData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    // Append the newly downloaded data
    [_downloadedData appendData:data];

    NSString* newStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:_downloadedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding ];
    NSLog(@"didReceiveData: %@",newStr);
}


- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    // Create an array to store the videos
    NSMutableArray *_videos = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    // Parse the JSON that came in
    NSError *error;
    NSArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:_downloadedData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
    NSLog(@"Connection failed! Error - %@ %@",
          [error localizedDescription],
          [[error userInfo] objectForKey:NSURLErrorFailingURLStringErrorKey]);

    // Loop through Json objects, create question objects and add them to our questions array
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.count; i++)
    {
        NSDictionary *jsonElement = jsonArray[i];

        // Create a new video object and set its props to JsonElement properties
        GetVideos1 *testVideo = [[GetVideos1 alloc] init];
        testVideo.IDVideo = jsonElement[@"IDVideo"];
        testVideo.title = jsonElement[@"title"];

        // Add this question to the locations array
        [_videos addObject:testVideo];
    }

    // Ready to notify delegate that data is ready and pass back items
    if (self.delegate)
    {
        [self.delegate itemsDownloaded:_videos];
    }
}
```

json is actually:

> [{"IDVideo":"6Joup252fR0","title":"Top 30 Baseball
>   Plays"},{"IDVideo":"aAy3Sh_RXjc","title":"MLB top
>   plays"},{"IDVideo":"bkiaAGOoLjc","title":"Top 50 most unforgettable
>   ejections"}]

But I cannot get to the data as it is part of the #text node name. How can I fetch the data?

Here is the php code that was used:

```
<?php 
// Check connection 
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) { 
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error(); 
} 
// Constructor - open DB connection 
function __construct() { 
$this->db = new mysqli('idirectorySQL.db.9960960.hostedresource.com', 'idirectorySQL', 'iDirectory70!', 'idirectorySQL'); 
$this->db->autocommit(FALSE); 
} 
$con=mysqli_connect('idirectorySQL.db.9960960.hostedresource.com', 'idirectorySQL', 'iDirectory70!', 'idirectorySQL');
// This SQL statement selects ALL from the table 'videos' 
$sql = "SELECT IDVideo,title FROM videos"; 
// Check if there are results 
if ($result = mysqli_query($con, $sql)) { 
// If so, then create a results array and a temporary one 
// to hold the data 
$resultArray = array(); 
$tempArray = array(); 
// Loop through each row in the result set 
while($row = $result->fetch_object()) { 
// Add each row into our results array 
$tempArray = $row; 
array_push($resultArray, $tempArray); 
}
// Close connections 
mysqli_close($con); 
// Finally, encode the array to JSON and output the results 
header('Content-type: application/json'); 
//  echo json_encode($resultArray, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT); 
echo json_encode($resultArray); 
} 
?>
```

I used

```
header('Content-type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
```

but I still received the same message. Also, this is what reads from the request headers:

```
Accept text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,/;q=0.8
```

Comment: You get `text/html` because you're requesting `text/html`

Comment: @vadian He's not requesting `text/html`. He specified a `Content-Type` of `text/html` (which is the format of the request, not the expected format of the response). If he wanted to specify that he was requesting JSON, then he'd set `Accept` to be `text/json` or `application/json`. Having said that, it is very curious to send a `text/html` request that has no `text/html` content. He should probably leave it blank, or specify a content type of something like `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. But I suspect a more fundamental web service problem (e.g. wrong URL, bug in web service, etc.).

Comment: Thank you @vadian. I used Vadian's code and the json error is Cocoa domain:3840 as the data is: <!-- pageok --> <!-- managed by puppet --> <html> <pre>pageok</pre> </html> NSJSONSerialization failed! Error - The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format. Again, data is part of the #text node name. I would sincerely appreciate your comments.

Comment: @Rob I use the File Manager in godaddy. Here is the code is used:

    <?php
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
    // Constructor - open DB connection
    function __construct() {
        $this->db = new mysqli('idirectorySQL.db.9960960.hostedresource.com', 'idirectorySQL', 'iDirectory70!', 'idirectorySQL');
        $this->db->autocommit(FALSE);
   }
$con=mysqli_connect('idirectorySQL.db.9960960.hostedresource.com', 'idirectorySQL', 'iDirectory70!', 'idirectorySQL');

Comment: // This SQL statement selects ALL from the table 'videos'
$sql = "SELECT IDVideo,title FROM videos";
// Check if there are results
if ($result = mysqli_query($con, $sql))
{
    // If so, then create a results array and a temporary one
 // to hold the data
 $resultArray = array();
 $tempArray = array();
 // Loop through each row in the result set
 while($row = $result->fetch_object())
 {
  // Add each row into our results array
  $tempArray = $row;
     array_push($resultArray, $tempArray);
 }

Comment: // Close connections
mysqli_close($con);
 // Finally, encode the array to JSON and output the results
    header('Content-type: application/json');
// echo json_encode($resultArray, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
        echo json_encode($resultArray);
}

?>

Comment: @Rob I used header('Content-type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded') but I still received the same message. Also, this is what reads from the request headers:

Accept text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8

Comment: First, in the future, don't put code in comments. In the future, edit your question and add this additional code at the end of the question. But from what I can divine so far is nothing that would generate "pageok" HTML. If you google "managed by puppet pageok" this looks like a common server configuration problem, not a coding problem (e.g. http://bx.com.au/blog/2013/02/godaddy-hosting-pageok-message/ or http://serverfault.com/questions/562324/pageok-given-by-puppet-instead-of-subdomain-files-hosted-on-godaddy.

Comment: @Rob thank you. I'll check and see whether this problem is a server config issue. [I put in the code in my question -- thanks]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't set any custom parameters in the `NSURLRequest`, `GET` is the default anyway.

As `NSURLConnection` is deprecated, this is a solution with the recommended `NSURLSession` API

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.scratchclass.com:80/videos/"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];           
[[[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData * data, NSURLResponse * response, NSError * error) {
    if (error) {
      NSLog(@"Connection failed! Error - %@ %@",
          [error localizedDescription],
          [[error userInfo] objectForKey:NSURLErrorFailingURLStringErrorKey]);
    } else {
      NSError *jsonError;
      NSArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&jsonError];
      if (jsonError) {
        NSLog(@"NSJSONSerialization failed! Error - %@ %@",
              [jsonError localizedDescription],
              [[jsonError userInfo] objectForKey:NSURLErrorFailingURLStringErrorKey]);
      } else {
        NSMutableArray *videos = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        for (NSDictionary *item in  jsonArray) {
          GetVideos1 *testVideo = [[GetVideos1 alloc] init];
          testVideo.IDVideo = item[@"IDVideo"];
          testVideo.title = item[@"title"];

          // Add this question to the locations array
          [videos addObject:item];
        }
        if (self.delegate) {
          [self.delegate itemsDownloaded:videos];
        }
      }
    }
}] resume];
```

Comment: Thank you Vadian and Rob. I used Vadian's code and the json error is Cocoa domain:3840 as the data is:
<!-- pageok -->
<!-- managed by puppet -->
<html>
<pre>pageok</pre>
</html>

NSJSONSerialization failed! Error - The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format. Again, data is part of the #text node name. I would sincerely appreciate your comments.

Comment: First I pasted the URL in a browser and got the expected JSON result. I'm frequently using a sample project to test network connections. The code worked.

Comment: It worked with your solution! The only difference is that I changed the url without the port! Thank you.